# What are the smooth map and the vector field in the Fig. 8.2, page 182 of John Lee's Smooth manifolds, 2nd

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

[image]

The purpose of this figure is to show that when $F$ is not surjective, then 
the differential of $F$ can't decide what vector can be assigned to the points outside of Im$F$ and when $F$ is not injective, then for some points of $N$, there may be several different vectors obtained by applying $dF$ to $X$ at different points of M.

But I find it hard to make up a concrete example of such map. I know to many professional geometricians, drawing pictures is enough to give such examples, but a beginner like me is still curious about(or suspect) the existence of such a map. This explains why I want to find an explicit, written-down example.

Specifically, are there a smooth vector field on $\mathbb S^1$ and a smooth map from $\mathbb S^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$ taking a unit circle to a "figure eight" that make trouble at the cross of "figure eight"?(Please note that the example I want is a smooth map and a vector field defined on the **whole** unit circle, not just an open arc of it)

Comment: Totally non-sequitur, but, I read it as "John Lee Smooth's", got incredibly jealous of his name, and wondered if 90's rappers were becoming great mathematicians.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x,y)=(2xy,y)$, which is clearly smooth on $S^1$ with image figure eight, It is not injective since it sends $(1,0),(-1,0)$ to O. Compute the pushforward(I hope it is correct)

$$df_{(x,y)}(\frac{d}{d\theta})=2(2x^2-1)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$$

Then $df_{(1,0)}(\frac{d}{d\theta})=2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ and $df_{(-1,0)}(\frac{d}{d\theta})=2\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, which gives two vectors at the cross.

$f$ is a composition of a stereographic projection, a homeomorphim between an open interval and the real line and a parametrization of figure eight. I thought at the beginning it is not extendable to the whole $S^1$, but after computations I found it is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take the vector field to be $\partial/\partial \theta$ and the figure eight curve to be an immersion that draws that figure. Then $dF_t(\partial/\partial \theta)$ is just $F'(t)$ (that just being the literal derivative with respect to $t$); if $t_1, t_2$ are the two points in $S^1$ sent to the bad point, then $F'(t_1) \neq F'(t_2)$, since the curve is going different directions! (Of course you could compute this by hand using whatever your parameterization of the figure eight curve is.)

The point of this figure is not to give an explicit counterexample, it's to get an idea of what could go wrong. This is an important skill you should try to develop; having to come  up with explicit counterexamples when the idea suffices can be a crippling problem.

Comment: Plus, I know few parametrizations of the figure eight. But if you meant the parametrization given in his example 4.19 on page 86. Then one of your $t_i$ has to correspond to the $\pi$ there, which is not in the domain of parametrization.

Comment: @TiWen I do not have my copy of his book. I'm sure you could prove that this gives you a smooth global vector field if you thought about it a bit. Another way of defining it is to think of $S^1$ as $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and defining this to be the image of $\partial/\partial x$ under the quotient map (which in this case actually defines a vector field on $S^1$, since this vector field is translation-invariant). I don't know what Lee's parameterization is. You can find an immersion $S^1 \to \Bbb R^2$ whose image is the figure-eight. If Lee writes an immersion from $(-\pi,\pi)$ I encourage you to see

Comment: ...how to write it, instead, as a map from $S^1$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that $\partial/\partial \theta$ is a global vector field on $S^1$ defined by gluing two angle coordinate charts(Example 8.4, page 176). However, the issue of the smooth map on $S^1$ still needs to be solved. I want to find out an explicit example because I even suspect the existence of it. BTW, I believe that UCLA should have an e-copy online of his book and it's not hard for you to get access.

Comment: You're right, it's probably on springerlink. I'll be fine without it.